# Index is still red after recovery in Elasticsearch. How to turn it green?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working with ES 2.2

After an index recovery with

```
POST /_snapshot/s3_repository/snapshot_traces_291215/_restore
{
    "include_global_state": false
}
```

My index is still red `red open traces_v2 3 1`

Here is the cluster health:

```
{
   "cluster_name": "burst",
   "status": "red",
   "timed_out": false,
   "number_of_nodes": 1,
   "number_of_data_nodes": 1,
   "active_primary_shards": 0,
   "active_shards": 0,
   "relocating_shards": 0,
   "initializing_shards": 0,
   "unassigned_shards": 6,
   "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
   "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
   "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
   "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
   "active_shards_percent_as_number": 0
}
```

I am sure the recovery was complete. I checked it with `GET /_cat/recovery?v`

`GET /_cat/_shards?v` gives me:

```
index     shard prirep state      docs store ip node 
traces_v2 2     p      UNASSIGNED                    
traces_v2 2     r      UNASSIGNED                    
traces_v2 1     p      UNASSIGNED                    
traces_v2 1     r      UNASSIGNED                    
traces_v2 0     p      UNASSIGNED                    
traces_v2 0     r      UNASSIGNED
```

Could be there any version incompatibility between a snapshot of 2.1 and ES 2.2?

Comment: you have 6 unassigned shards and 0 active shards - this is bad. View the detailed shard information by running `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v"`

Comment: I have edited my question to paste the result

Answer (score 0):

I forced the assignation of the primaries shards to my node by.

```
GET _cluster/reroute
{
    "commands" : [ {
          "allocate" : {
              "index" : "traces_v2", 
              "shard" : "2", 
              "node" : "Killer Shrike", 
              "allow_primary" : true
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

But the status was still Yellow because I run ES on a single node and I had 3 replica shards. And replica shards can't run on a node that already has primary shard.

So I deleted them by setting the number of replica shards by index to 0.

```
PUT /_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}
```

I hope this will help other noob people like me!